# WordPress Virtual Page - "Trying to get property 'post_type' of non-object"

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-plugin-creation

I'm building a WordPress plugin that uses a virtual page to display the data fetched from the API.

The setup is relatively simple. I have a rewrite rule for the URLs on which the plugin is meant to work and when I hit specific query_vars I start the virtual page.

```
public function __construct()
{

    require_once plugin_dir_path(__FILE__).'vendor/autoload.php';

    add_action('init', [$this, 'rewrite_rule'], 1);

    // add query vars
    add_action('query_vars', [$this, 'add_query_vars_filter'], 1);

    // virtual page init
    add_filter('the_posts', [$this, 'virtual_page'], 1);

}
public function virtual_page($posts)
{

    global $wp, $wp_query;

    if (!empty(get_query_var('plugin'))) {
        $plugin = get_query_var('plugin');
    }

    if (!empty($plugin)) {

        $post = new stdClass();
        $post->post_author = 1;
        $post->post_name = 'lorem ipsum';
        $post->guid = get_bloginfo('wpurl').'/';

        $post->post_title = 'title';
        $post->post_content = 'content';

        $post->ID = -999;
        $post->post_type = 'page';
        $post->post_status = 'static';
        $post->comment_status = 'closed';
        $post->ping_status = 'open';
        $post->comment_count = 0;
        $post->post_date = current_time('mysql');
        $post->post_date_gmt = current_time('mysql', 1);
        $posts = NULL;
        $posts[] = $post;

        $wp_query->is_page = true;
        $wp_query->is_single = false;

        $wp_query->is_singular = true;
        $wp_query->is_home = false;
        $wp_query->is_archive = false;
        $wp_query->is_category = false;

        unset($wp_query->query["error"]);
        $wp_query->query_vars["error"] = "";
        $wp_query->is_404 = false;

        remove_filter('the_content', 'wpautop');
        remove_filter('the_excerpt', 'wpautop');

        return $posts;
    }
}
```

This code does what is expected which is display the Virtual Page with content I need but I get a warning in PHP 8.0 :

```
"Attempt to read property "post_type" on null"
```

[image]

I believe the execution order is wrong here because I get empty $post & $wp_query in xdebug. I'm guessing that the virtual page function is being executed too early.

I was trying to debug this issue for a long time but unfortunately I'm lacking backend / WordPress knowledge.

If anyone could help I'm going to be more thankful.

Answer (score 0):

If You try to work with a Virtual Page in WP 6.1 you cannot have a post ID anymore. This line was causing it to break.

`$post->ID = -999;`